# How to create two figures on a single Drag and drop in GEF?

Tags: eclipse-gef

I like to create two figure on a single drag and drop form the palette i.e At a single drag and drop two figures should be created both have separate EditPart and Model class.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is multiple ways to make this happen: the easiest is to make you creationFactory return 
an array or a list of objects. Then, in you

```
protected Command getCreateCommand(final CreateRequest request) {
   if (request.getNewObject() instanceof List<?>/Object[]) {
     ...
   }
}
```

or, the other way is to sublcass CreationTool to have a List of creation factories. Then, create a custom request type, for example,

```
public class MultiCreateRequest extends Request {
    ...    
}
```

and override getCommand(Request request) dispatching method that it will handle that case:

```
public Command getCommand(Request request) {
   if (REQ_MULTI_CREATE.equals(request.getType()))
      return getMultiCreateCommand((MultiCreateRequest) request);
}
```

when subclassing creation tool you should pay you attention to:

```
Constructor
createTargetRequest() (return MultiCreateRequest)
getCommandName() (return REQ_MULTI_CREATE)
getCreateRequest() (specify)
selectAddedObject(EditPartViewer viewer) (to select all created that way objects)
updateTargetRequest() (specify)
```

Oh, i've actually came up with the idea, that creation new Tool subclassing TargetingTool is a better idea then subclassing CreationTool. Instead, you can just copy implementation (it's easy actually) and change it as you need.

Comment: thanks for your answer! as you said by the first method created array of object and got 2 request objects as array created 2 command objects also. but how i can i return 2 objects. i tried with compoundcommand but its not drawing any thing on the editor.Pls help me thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah, and then you should create CompoundCommand. It it's not working, try to accurately trace/debug each command execution separately, to see why it now working.

Comment: debug control is not at all coming to the execute method which am implemented from abstract class CompoundCommand.

Comment: I can't check it now, but AFAIK CompoundCommand is not an AbstractClass, it's something you can apply regular commands to. Much like: CompoundCommand cc = new CompoundCommand(); cc.apply(cmd1); cc.apply(cmd2);

Comment: Thanks for time.yes as you said CompoundCommand is not an AbstractClass,i made it work. but while moving the diagram around the canvas it says classCastexception cannot convert from toolbarlayout to xylayout.

Comment: Check you move commands and container's figure layouts and constraints. They're not matching probably ;) And mark an answer as assepted if it was helpful.

Comment: I made it work by executing like cc.execute(). if am not doing it nothing is coming in the canvas.

Comment: You shouldn't do a cc.extcute(), you shuold just return a command from the getCommand(Request req) method, and it will be executed on editDomain's command stack.

Comment: wow quick answering... but the XYLayoutEditPolicy.getCreateCommand() return type is command so its not excecuting...

Comment: used unwrap() method and it works thanks for your help and support